# Android StackScrollLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I need help creating a `Layout` like the one Android uses to render notifications inside it's notification Panel.

[image]

[image]

Basically what happens at the end of the view when notifications don't fit the screen anymore is what interests me. [Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/stack/NotificationStackScrollLayout.java) is the view in Android source code.

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so the link above is for the master branch (nougat). I found the lollipop branch to be a bit less complex. Also a Recyclerview.LayoutManager could work pretty well. Anyone got any experience / idea to help me out with where I got stuck at?

Comment: Just managed to import the layout into my app. But when I'm adding new items inside the ViewGroup it hides them for whatever reason. Any help? I could provide the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

1-Include the view inside your layout xml

```
<com.bartoszlipinski.flippablestackview.FlippableStackView
    android:id="@+id/stack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

2-FlippableStackView is based on the specific PageTransformer used with the ViewPager. Therefore to fill the View you can use just a typical implementation of a PagerAdapter. In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), setup all the parameters of the FlippableStackView.

```
 FlippableStackView stack = (FlippableStackView) findViewById(R.id.stack);
    stack.initStack(2);
    stack.setAdapter(mStackAdapter);
        //assuming mStackAdapter contains your initialized adapter
```

3-Important Note: The current implementation of the library will display the elements from the Adapter in the reverse order. In other words: view at position 0 of your adapter will be displayed at the bottom of the stack and view at position adapter.getCount()-1 will be visible first (available for the first flip).

for a working example and reference check the library here
[FlippableStackView](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this library. But it looks like something needs to be modified there to allow a normal scroll of items (the center group) and show them completely while only stacking the bottom ones that no longer fit the screen.

Comment: Sorry unfortunately this library can't do it.